# How can I add counter to remove duplicate words in a string algorithm?

Tags: arrays, c, string, algorithm

I have this algorithm that removes duplicate words in a string:

```
int main()
{
    char str[100], word[100], doubleArr[10][30];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, len1 = 0, len2 = 0, l = 0, n, c = 0;

    printf("Enter the string\n");
    gets(str);
    n = strlen(str);

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            doubleArr[k][j] = '\0';
            k++;
            j = 0;
        } else {
            doubleArr[k][j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    doubleArr[k][j] = '\0';

    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (l = 1; l < k + 1; l++) {
            if (doubleArr[l][j] == '\0' || l == i) {
                continue;
            }

            if (strcmp(doubleArr[i], doubleArr[l]) == 0) {
                doubleArr[l][j] = '\0';
            }
        }
    }

    j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
        if (doubleArr[i][j] == '\0') {
            continue;
        } else {
            printf("%s ", doubleArr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And I need make a counter of duplicate words in a string.

When I try to put the counter in different places of the code, I always get wrong results.

Comment: What is this `gets()` function?

Comment: @emblox Your code does not remove duplicated words in a string.

Comment: @emblox And the array word is not used. So the code does not make sense. Also it is unclear why there are used magic numbers10 and 30 in this declaration  doubleArr[10][30]

Comment: The function gets() receives and reads a structure from the standard input stream and puts it into the specified array of argument.

Comment: My code removes duplicate words and leaves only one from the list

Comment: And is it part of the C standard anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the duplicates, just increment a counter when you detect one, after the test `if (strcmp(doubleArr[i], doubleArr[l]) == 0)`

Note however that there are many small problems in your code:

- you should never use `gets()`
- you should only increment the word count `k` when the current word has at least 1 character.
- the count of words may be incorrect if the sentence does not end with a space: increment it after the end of the loop if `j > 0` and use `k` in the rest of the code instead of `k + 1`.
- the code has undefined behavior if any of the words are longer than 29 characters or if there are more than 10 words because of buffer overflows.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[100], words[50][100];
    int i, j, k, n, dup;

    // input the string with fgets
    printf("Enter the string\n");
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
        return 1;

    // extract the words from the string
    j = n = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        // use space and newline as word separators
        if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n') {
            if (j > 0) {
                // add a new word if not empty
                words[n][j] = '\0';
                n++;
                j = 0;
            }
        } else {
            words[n][j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    // add the last word if not empty
    if (j > 0) {
        words[n][j] = '\0';
        n++;
    }

    // remove duplicates
    dup = 0;
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0)
                break;
        }
        if (j == k) {
            // keep this word
            if (i != k) {
                strcpy(words[k], words[i]);
            }
            k++;
        } else {
            // omit this word
            dup++;
        }
    }
    // update word count
    n = k;

    // output the word list
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s%c", words[i], " \n"[i == n - 1]);
    }
    printf("%d duplicates\n", dup);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create some global variable, say `int counter = 0;`.

So your `if` statement in line 32 should look like:

```
    if (strcmp (doubleArr[i], doubleArr[l]) == 0) {
            doubleArr[l][j] = '\0';
            counter += 1;
    }
```

Then you can print it wherever you want:

```
    printf("%d", counter);
```

Comment: i think this is the answer....